# Ruby cramp authentication with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, rubygems

There is RubyOnRails application with Devise authentication. Is there any smart way to add ruby Cramp framework to that application with devise support?
One devise session for both rails and cramp

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to run Cramp for something like chat within your application. If you provided more info about what you are trying to accomplish, it would help get you a more appropriate answer. If you're building a chat tool, or some kind of stat logging service, it would probably make more sense to build it outside of Rails and integrate the two through an API. Just a thought.